# Enabling write access to partition

Tags: partitioning, mount, permissions

I have a recently formatted partition in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS running system with large chunk of disk space allocated to it. It does not mount by default when the computer starts up, and is not writable to either. It's pretty annoying that I can't use it.
So, how do I enable the write access to a me, sole user?

The output of `df -T` command returns following details:

```
Filesystem     Type     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on`
/dev/sda3      ext4     503834856    71520 478146904   1% /media/deependra/e4da4ac5-3b38-4b89-9402-397eb940e4d3
```

Also, How do I enable the partition to auto-mount on starting the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partitions will mount at boot if they are specified in the file `/etc/fstab` and you can also set the mount options here to ensure it will be writable.

The Ubuntu help wiki has [a good page about fstab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) and you can also see the [fstab](/questions/tagged/fstab) [tag wiki](https://askubuntu.com/tags/fstab/info)

First, make a mount point for your partition in `/media`, for example,

```
sudo mkdir /media/storage
```

Then make a backup of your `fstab`

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab-bak
```

Then get the UUID of the partition to be mounted. Since you know the partition you want is `/dev/sda3` you can `grep` for it

```
sudo blkid | grep sda3
```

The output will look something like:

```
/dev/sda3: UUID="4ee1bbce-9d64-44b6-821b-511e06a804e0" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="482d7ecc-43f2-4c1b-985d-21b42999ed84"
```

Copy the long string after `UUID` between "quotes", from your listing, in my case `4ee1bbce-9d64-44b6-821b-511e06a804e0` is what I would copy.

Now open your `/etc/fstab` for editing in your favourite text editor, using `sudo`, for example

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

at the end of the file, make a new entry using the UUID string you copied, the mount point you made earlier, the filesystem type, mount options and `0 0` at the end, for example:

```
UUID=4ee1bbce-9d64-44b6-821b-511e06a804e0 /media/storage ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Everything must be in the right order and separated by spaces. `defaults` will mount an ext4 partition as writable. If you want to add more mount options, they should be separated by commas and no spaces (see the documentation)

Comment: That solves the latter question quite well. But, the other issue is about enabling write access to the partition. When viewed the permission tab under device properties, it reads "You are not the owner, so you cannot change these permissions". How do I grant my user the owner permission?

Comment: @DeependraDhakal you can recursively `chown` the mountpoint `sudo chown -R $USER: /media/storage`